# how to set jquery combo box as selected true

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a jquery combo box whose selected value I am storing in a session.

After I retrieve the value from the session(which contains Json data) I want to again make the combobox to be selected for the same value,

i am trying to do something like this but does not seem to work.

```
var myArrayVar=JSON.parse(document.getElementById("populateDT").innerHTML);
alert(myArrayVar[0].ActionMessage);
if(myArrayVar[0].ActionMesssage == "Error Message")
{
            document.getElementById("combobox").value="error";
            document.getElementById("combobox").selected=true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a select element?
See an example, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/N4v3u/

```
document.getElementById('sel').value = 'saab'; // your value here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if (myArrayVar[0].ActionMesssage == "Error Message")

    //Assign select to a variable
    var select = document.getElementById("combobox");

    //Loop and find!
    for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        if (select.options[i].value == "error") {
            select.options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This will loop through each of your options, find the value of `error`, and set it to selected.